# Single place for maven projects versions

Tags: maven

We have a large projects tree of maven projects and subprojects and we want ensure that all pom's have the same artifact version.

So in each pom this version is placed twice - as artifact version and parent artifact version.

How can I put this version number only once (in parent pom or in properties file) instead putting it twice to each pom?

Thank you

Comment: This is actually a no problem. Maven Release plugin updates all submodules versions. It even asks if a different then the parent version id should be used.

Comment: @Boris Pavlović yes. I guess you must have SCM configured, though.

Comment: @Boris you don't need the release plugin, you can set versions without doing a release with the [versions maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the version number from the child projects and they will inherit it from the parent.

Comment: But still I should in every project write parent version, isn't it?

Comment: @user20391 - Yes that's true.

Answer (score 0):

If your projects are *real* subprojects (share the same release/lifecycle as the parent) you should integrate them as modules in their parents.
See [the maven reference, 3.6.2. Multi-module vs. Inheritance](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit)
This way the maven-release-plugin can handle all the versions of the subprojects at once.

If your projects are not really subprojects but mere dependencies (with a release/lifecycle on their own), then there's no way around doing all the release/versionmanagement stuff for each project on its own. At least I haven't found one :(